# How to add a dynamic columns while retrieving values from two tables using sql or pl/sql?

Tags: sql, plsql, hana

I have come across the following interesting situation in SQL. I am  looking for help/advice to solve this situation from experts here.

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2.

Table 1 has following fields:

`R_ID| R_NUMBER | DIRECTION |FROM_KM | TO_KM`
`1      335        A         10         15`
`2      335        B         11         13` 
`3      770        A         15.5       18.7`
`4      770        B         15         19`
`5      5510       1         15.95      17.35`

Table 2 as below

`R_ID| R NUMBER | DIRECTION |KM LOCATION`
`1      335         A          10`
`2   335         A          10.3`
`3   335         A          10.5`
`4   335         A          10.7`
`5   335         A          11`
`6   335         B          12`
`7   335         B          12.5`
`8   335         B          13`
`9   770         A          15`
`10  770         B          16.5`
`11  770         A          17`
`12  770         A          18.5`
`13  770         B          19`
`16  5510        1          15.97`
`17  5510        1          15.99`
`18  5510        1          16.07`
`19  5510        1          16.17`
`20  5510        1          16.27`
`21  5510        1          16.37`
`22  5510        1          16.47`
`23  5510        1          16.47`
`24  5510        1          16.57`
`25  5510        1          16.67`
`26  5510        1          16.77`
`27  5510        1          16.87`
`28  5510        1          16.97`
`29  5510        1          17.07`
`30  5510        1          17.17`
`31  5510        1          17.27`
`32  5510        1          17.35`
`33  5510        1          17.37`
`34  5510        1          18.37`

I would like to join two tables based on route number, direction and populate "KM location field" of table2 dynamically in between the range of " from_km" & "to_km" values of table 1.

Expectation as follows:

`R_ID| R_NUMBER | DIRECTION |FROM_KM | TO_KM | KM_LOCATION`
`1        335         A        10        15     10,10.3,10.5,10.7,11`
`2        335         B        11        13     12,12.5,13`
`3        770         A        15.5      18.7   15,17,18.5`
`4        770         B        15        19     16.5,19`
`5        5510        1        15.95     17.35  15.97,............., 17.35`

Moreover, ID: 33, 34 of table2 should not be included in the results as it falls out of range for the fields from_km, to_km of table1

I tried simple join between two tables but I encounter having duplicate entries of route id of table1 for all matching tuples.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added sample data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

as from the description of the requirement,assuming the database is oracle (11 and above) listagg and pivot functions should suffice...
example:

```
select t1.route_id,
      t1.route_number,
      t1.direction,
      t1.from_km,
      t1.to_km
      ,
      (select listagg(km_location,',') from     table2 t2
where t2.route_number=t1.route_number
and t2.direction=t1.direction) as km_loc
from table1 t1;

-- output:

ROUTE_ID    ROUTE_NUMBER    DIRECTION   FROM_KM TO_KM   KM_LOC
1   335 A   10  15  10,15,11,10.7,10.5,10.3
2   335 B   11  13  12,13,12.5
3   770 A   15.5    18.7    17,18.5
4   770 B   15  19  16.5,19
```

if wanted km_loc in separate columns, please use pivot function.

if need more, kindly share the query you tried and the exact problems you faced...

if it's in PLSQL, we can have dynamic select query by having execute immediate command to have the requirement...

Comment: I am working on HANA data base. I used STRING_AGG function which has same property as listagg function.  It works fine, all values of KM_location of table are included in the result set of considered join condition. Whereas, I am looking for an output which only includes the values of KM_location of table 2 considering the range between "from_km" , "to_km" fields of table1. for example, 33, 34 rows of table2 should not be included in the results as it falls out of range for the fields from_km, to_km of table1.